# Error in Writing in app.config

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, app-config

I am trying to write an object in my `app.config` file.

When i reach the following line

```
windowMain.config.Sections["LayoutSettings"].SectionInformation.SetRawXml("<LayoutSettings>" + XElement.Parse(str).ToString() + "</LayoutSettings>");
```

There is no error in the `XElement.Parse(str).ToString()`, it is having correct value.
`windowMain.config.Sections["LayoutSettings"]` is shown `null`, however the count of the sections is shown one,...but already there is a config section and section name Layout Settings in it.

The following exception is thrown:

`An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for LayoutSettings: Could not load file or assembly 'Sigma' or one of its dependencies.`

My `app.config` has the following code in the `configsection`:

```
<section name="LayoutSettings" type="Sigma.Modules.ParentWindowState, Sigma" />
```

I have checked the type of the section , its correct, but unable to get the problem and get the above exception.

Comment: The handler is located in an assembly `Sigma.Modules.ParentWindowState, Sigma`. Sure you have that assembly referenced?

Comment: yes..i have referenced that assembly...